# MATLAB get filed values of several structs summarised in an array

Tags: matlab

I have a folder containing some images. When I use `dir` I get an array with an entry for each image. This entry is an struct with the fields `name`, `date`, `bytes` and some more...

Now I want to have an array, containing the name of x images, selected by an index array `index=[2 8 15 23]`. How can I do this without using loops (to improve performance)?
How can I access the field value of the structs summarised in my array getting with `dir`?

Using

```
images=dir('path_to_my_folder');
index=[2 8 15 23];
names=images(index).name;
```

doesn't work, this only returns the name of the last image accessed by `index(end)`

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code `images(index).name` gives a [comma-separated list](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html) of strings. When assigning a list to a variable, only the first element of the list gets assigned.

To assign all elements, you need to collect the elements of that list into a cell array, and then assign the cell array to the variable:

```
names = {images(index).name};
```